# Trying to save a .psd on a Mac network drive fails

Tags: windows-7, macos, adobe-photoshop, network-drive

For some reason, trying to save a Photoshop (CS5.1) document fails to save on my network drive. (Mac)

**This only happens with .psd files. All other formats work just fine.**

[image: Error]

**Does anyone know what is going on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe does not support opening and saving files from a network drive. I know this is weird but that is their official response.

Obviously something is wrong but it's probably with the Mac network drive. Try updating your Mac.

Comment: I don't like that. :P It's stupid that file access from a network drive isn't supported officially.

Comment: `[citation needed]` – I really find that hard to believe! And why would you need to update the Mac if it's not possible anyway?

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3521942#3521942

Comment: Still don't like it.

Comment: So it *should* work after all? The post clearly says that it might just be a problem with the network layer, not that Photoshop itself doesn't support it. (Btw please ping me next time, otherwise I don't get a reply)